# converting the index of 1D array into 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, indexing

How can I convert the index of 1D array into 2D array?  I know how to convert a 2D array into 1D `(i*the size of row+j)`. I want the opposite of that.

Comment: Can you share some code and an example of what you're trying to achieve? It's a bit hard to follow the question as it's currently phrased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to know is: How many columns should the 2D array have:
Lets say you have an array of 20 columns and 10 rows (array[20,10]):

```
int index  = 47;
int numberOfColumns = 20;
int column = index % numberOfColumns;
int row    = index / numberOfColumns;

// column == 7
// row    == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the opposite. if n is the length of the row and x is index in 1D. You can index like

```
array[x/n][x%n]
```